# Drag and drop text to a cell in Excel using Office JS

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js

How can I drag a text from (a node from a treeview) in TaskPane and add it to the dropped cell in Excel using Office JS. I have tried HTML 5 drag and drop

```
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

But I dont know what to use inside `ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));` instead of `data`

Kindly note that I don't need to use jQuery like what was used in the Wikipedia Office add-in sample.

Answer (score 1):

Drag and drop is not supported. There is no easy substitute here. If the scenario doesn't require a lot of drag-drops, you could use the double-click (on add-in taskpane) to update current active cell with the data and move cell selection to next logical cell (right, down, etc.) to allow next update.

Comment: But how come it works for Excel's Wikipedia Addin? [Refer Here](https://giphy.com/gifs/3oz8xDNucQkaNyZOvu)

Comment: Do you wish to drag from Excel to taskpane or taskpane to Excel? Wikipedia add-in only supports the former, no?

Comment: I wish "taskpane to Excel". Its supported in Wikipedia. Please refer the file attached.